# How to setState in React when async mapping through array and API call

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I'm trying to map() through my state, favorites, in React to fetch data from each entry in the state. The data should be stored in another state, stocks, and be displayed in a table.

Map() through the state and fetching the data works, and I can see the date in the console log. But it will not be stored in the state.

How do I add the data to the state?

Here is the code:

```
  // Calling the function on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
      tableFetch();
  }, []);

  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(["aapl", "arlv"]);
  const [stocks, setStocks] = useState([]);

    // fetch symbol data and stores it in stocks
      const tableFetch = () => {
        favorites.map( async (favorites) => {
          const data = await fetch(
                `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${favorites}/quote?token=${token}`
              );
          const stocksData = await data.json();
          console.log(stocksData)
          setStocks(stocksData);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here you have a few issues.**

1. When you make an API call after getting a response, the state will get overridden with new data or might be issued with scope availability

**suggestion:**
2. Why don't you make multiple API calls and when they settle, collect all the information then setState.

```
useEffect(() => {
    tableFetch();
  }, []);

  const tableFetch = async () => {
    // Note: the below code will create urls & make parallel calls
    let axiosFetch = favorites.reduce((axiosCalls, url) => {
      axiosCalls.push(axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${url}`));
      return axiosCalls;
    }, []);

    // Here promises will settle and will collect all the data.
    await axios
      .all(axiosFetch)
      .then((data) => {
        let dataCollected = data.reduce((dataCollected, response) => {
          dataCollected = dataCollected.concat(response.data.data);
          return dataCollected;
        }, []);
        // After collecting all the data we can set data into state at once.
        setStocks(dataCollected);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("collect errors", error);
      });
  };
```

[Sample Code Example, you can play around](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-multiple-calls-25kq3)

> Note: I was using Axios library, the same thing can be done using fetch too.

Comment: Do you have any solution for receiving a json? :)

Comment: Do you mean to say, using fetch instead of Axios library?

Comment: Axios is good and have been mening to try it so that works :). The data that I'm pulling from the API is a json format, and the code you made does push it to the state. However, the data is undefined. If you look at my code I use data.json(), but I cant seem to figure out how to transform the API data with your code. :)

Comment: In your code you are using the fetch method, So we get data in the form of JSON itself. Using this code `data.json()` we are converting from JSON to object.

Axios library will also get JSON data but it will convert from JSON to object by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have done these changes using fetch, hope It will be helpful.

```
 const tableFetch = async () => {
    // Note: the below code will create urls & make parallel calls
    let urls = favorites.reduce((axiosCalls, url) => {
      axiosCalls.push(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${url}`);
      return axiosCalls;
    }, []);

    const texts = await Promise.all(
      urls.map(async (url) => {
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        return resp.json();
      })
    );

    let dataCollected = texts.reduce((dataCollected, response) => {
      dataCollected = dataCollected.concat(response.data);
      return dataCollected;
    }, []);
    // After collecting all the data we can set data into state at once.
    setStocks(dataCollected);
  };
```

[POC Link using fetch method](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-multiple-calls-25kq3?file=/src/App.js)